# hibernate session not reading updated data in next(new) session created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I am using Hibernate and spring in my web-app. On one forms submit i save some data in a table. the same controller that  handles the submit redirects the page to another form. i.e. to another form controller. this form must use some data  depending on the data submitted in last form before opening.i create a new hibernate session to fetch data.

but for some reason it is not able to read updated data from the table( it reads old data). 
I have make sure to commit the transaction (It do save data i have checked in data base.) I also made sure to close session.

I create a new session for each request and close this session, before moving back to view.

Why hibernate is not able to read new data?

Comment: Did you try the saveAndFlush method? Also flush and clear the entityManager could help you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially i believed its cache problem but since second level cache is not applied and session is new in new form so first level cache is also not a problem.

what exactly is the problem is still a mystery but i got a work-around

i added following property in my configuration with value 2

"hibernate.connection.isolation"

It fixed my problem. but More details about it is welcome as I am not clear what is this about.