# Old data in result from new hibernate session

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions, isolation

I faced an issue that a process receives old data from newly-opened hibernate session whereas that data is updated by another process through committed transaction and closing session after that. If I connect to database directly I can see the updated data. The Hibernate version is `4.1.9` and database is `MySQL 5.6`.

After reading a lot of similar problems I made sure that it's not caused neither by first level cache - new session is opened each time, nor by second level cache - it's not enabled. I also tried different options like flushing session after transaction and etc. but the hibernate was still returning old data instead of updated. Then I found quite old post on hibernate forum describing the same problem which was fixed by setting **hibernate.connection.isolation** to 2 (TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED). I gave a try to such approach and it works for me as well.

So actually the question why such change could be required for Hibernate and MySQL having default configuration, could someone please explain ?

p.s. I spent hours for solving this problem, but didn't find such solution on so. so may be it will save time for other people in the same situation.

p.p.s While posting this question I finally found another. So posted with the same problem and solution. but at the same time there are also many other similar questions without replies. May be one more post will give more chance to find the solution.

[Link to the post at hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=928420)

[Link to to the similar post at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092020/hibernate-session-not-reading-updated-data-in-nextnew-session-created)

Comment: That changing the isolation level affects your observations strongly suggests that the "read transaction" was initiated *before* the "write transaction" was committed.

Comment: I don't know what isolation level Hibernate was using before you specified `READ COMMITED`, but if it used MySQL's default of `REPEATABLE READ` then the "read transaction" would have continued using the snapshot established on its first read even after the "write transaction" was committed.

Comment: eggyal, you're right! According to the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) by default it's REPEATABLE READ. So i guess anyone who wants to read updates in database should change it.

Comment: Usually people want transactions to be based off consistent state, so interim commits from other transactions are unhelpful.  But the isolation settings exist to support different use cases, so if you need `READ COMMITTED` then that's what you should use.  However, I would query whether these transactions really need to overlap or whether this is in fact indicative of the "read transaction" being held open for too long?

Comment: In case of read operation i do open session but i don't begin any transaction explicitly. Is it a recommended practice to have explicit transaction for even read/query ?

Comment: If you're not explicitly using transactions, I presume you're autocommitting every statement?  In which case each statement would (implicitly) comprise its own transaction, and you shouldn't observe any difference between `READ COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE READ`.

Comment: I do use explicit transactions for write operations, but i don't use them for read operations. At the same time, most of settings in hibernate and mysql are left as default and in the application log file i can see that autocommit is false: 

(JdbcTransaction) DEBUG: initial autocommit status: false

Comment: Then you just have one big transaction that's never committed, even if the only statements in there are `SELECT` ones.